# How to control the scope of event listeners in the extjs app controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Ext JS - v 6.2.1

I'm interested in reusing a main component developed in ExtJs which i've written in different tabs of the tabpanel. The main component is composed of two child components and each of these components have their respective controllers and the child components interact among themselves. Since the event listeners are added in the controller domain the events fired in one instance of tab affects the other tabs as well.

Pseudo code of the scenario explained

```
*********** Views ***********

Ext.define('MainApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainapp-main',  
    controller: 'main',

    ...

    items: [{
        title: 'Main Component Instance 1',
        closable: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'mainapp-maincomponent'
        }]
    }, {
        title: 'Main Component Instance 2',
        closable: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'mainapp-maincomponent'
        }]
    }]
});


Ext.define('MainApp.view.maincomponent.MainComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainapp-maincomponent',
    controller: 'maincomponent',

    ...

    items: [{ 
            xtype: 'mainapp-component1'
        },{
            xtype: 'mainapp-component2'
    }]
});

Ext.define('MainApp.view.component1.Component1', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainapp-component1',    
    controller: 'component1',

    ...

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        cls: 'contactBtn',
        scale: 'large',
        text: 'Fire Event',
        handler: 'onComponentButtonTapped'
    }]
});

Ext.define('MainApp.view.component2.Component2', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainapp-component2',    
    controller: 'component2',

    ...

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        value: 'Button is not clicked yet',
        width: 500,
        readOnly: true
    }]
});

*********** Controllers ***********

Ext.define('MainApp.view.component1.Component1Controller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    alias: 'controller.component1',

    onComponentButtonTapped: function (btn, eventArgs) {
        this.fireEvent('component1ButtonTapped', btn, eventArgs);
    }
});

Ext.define('MainApp.view.component2.Component2Controller', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.component2',
    listen: {
        controller: {
            'component1': {
                component1ButtonTapped: 'onComponent1ButtonTapped'
            }
        }
    },

    onComponent1ButtonTapped: function(){
        this.getView().down('textfield').setValue(Ext.String.format('Button tapped at {0}', Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d H:i:s')));
    }
});
```

Can somebody please suggest the correct way of addressing this used case.

**More Details**

The tab panel is loaded in viewport

```
Tab 1 has first instance of Main Component  - M1
Tab 2 has second instance of Main Component - M2
```

Every instance of Main Component has two child components

```
Component1 - M1C1 > M1C1 View and M1C1 Controller
Component2 - M1C2 > M1C2 View and M1C2 Controller
```

Similarly for the second instance of Main Component

```
Component1 - M2C1 > M2C1 View and M2C1 Controller
Component2 - M2C2 > M2C2 View and M2C2 Controller
```

Requirement here is to restrict Actions done on M1C1 view should be processed by M1C2 Controller only.

```
Issue is that with the code above M2C2 Controller also listens to the event
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `handler: 'onComponentButtonTapped'` to

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    cls: 'contactBtn',
    scale: 'large',
    text: 'Fire Event',
    listeners: {
        click: 'onComponentButtonTapped',
        scope: SCOPE-YOU-WANT
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, following the approach which you suggested doesn't solve my problem. I'm not sure if my question was clear enough. I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe you are overnesting in your `MainApp.view.main.Main` component and you don't use a layout for your overnesting either. That can lead to unnecessary consequences like extra layout runs and bloated DOM affecting performance.

Ok, onto your question! I don't think scope is what you're actually after here. I see it as how to properly architect your ViewControllers. While understanding this isn't your real code, I will say that in this example you don't need that `Component1Controller` controller. Get rid of it and the button's handler will get resolved up to the `maincomponent` controller which is where you can control both child items. I only say this fully knowing that your `Component1Controller` is likely doing other things so it's not going anywhere just to say that not all containers need controllers. It also serves what I would do in this case if `Component1Controller` is to stick around. Instead of firing an event on the `Component1Controller` instance and use the event domain to get to `Component2Controller`, I would fire a view event on `Component1` and add a listener on your config object so that `maincomponent` controller gets the event to do it's thing.

That sounds messy and hard to follow so I created this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ic9).